# Debian error message "Failed to access perfctr msr..."

Tags: debian, virtualbox

I installed Debian (8.2.0) on Virtualbox and I always get the error message :
[image]

Is the system affected by the error messages? What does the messages mean? And how do I get rid of it?

Answer (score 2):

It's not an error, it says that the CPU doesn't support performance counters.

Virtualbox probably just doesn't emulate this. You probably won't notice the difference anyway.